# \Needspace inside \multline

Tags: spacing, multline

How to make `\Needspace` work inside `\multline`? 
`\displaybreak` would be ok, but it doesn't support arbitrary lengths.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{needspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
%e\Needspace{10cm}\\   % this doesn't work
f\\
g\\
h\\
i
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `\needspace{} before the `multiline`?

Comment: @Peter. Because it will produce unwanted result.

Comment: Only second part of equations should go to the second page.

Comment: Use `\displaybreak[4]` where you want the display is split. Defer these kind of adjustments to the final revision of the document, when you'll know that the text is in final form.

Comment: That's not a deal. The document must be built correctly in all cases. I'm sure Latex provides the possibility to insert conditional `\displaybreak[4]`. Ultimately, it provides the possibility to insert conditional `\pagebreak`. Why can't this be conditional `\displaybreak[4]`?

Comment: What about using `\displaybreak[3]` instead? Then it will only break if required by the location on the page and you won't have to do manual adjustments.